# Creating FTP server in OS X using Twisted framework

Tags: macos, ftp, twisted

I want to create FTP server on OSX which will fetch files and folders structure from my server and show in OSX's file system.

I got the link of twisted framework but not got any idea how to use this

[Twisted Framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/)

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `twistd` command line application to start a basic FTP server:

```
twistd-2.7 -no ftp --root=.
```

Note that the documentation says that this is probably not secure, so I would not recommend using this aside from testing and quick file transfers on trusted networks.

---

Edit: based on your comment, you want to "show files and folders structure in mac os file system", you probably don't need Twisted.

You can connect to an FTP server from Finder by going to menu "Go->Connect To Server" and typing `ftp://your.server.address.com` then entering your username and password at the prompt.

Here's a link to instructions with screenshots: https://igppwiki.ucsd.edu/groups/publichelpwiki/wiki/d0cc0/How_to_Mount_an_FTP_Server_on_Mac_OSX.html

Comment: @ Peter Gibson: Thanks for reply but I want to show files and folders structure in mac os file system, which is on my server. Same like GoogleDrive,Dropbox client did.

Comment: @ Peter Gibson: Thanks, But my server does not implemented the interface for that. I have to access that files and folders structure through REST API. So for this I want to create intermediate server which takes file and folder structure from my web server and show in finder.

Comment: @ Peter Gibson: I tried with your suggestion but it is very slow and it hangs finder and make it unresponsive.